# How to Setup TSLint for Definitely Typed

Tags: visual-studio-code, definitelytyped, tslint

I made a change to a file for Definitely Typed, and when I created a pull request, it failed because of a formatting error.  I'm assuming this is TsLint.  I've never set it up before.  How do I get it setup locally so I can catch these errors before committing using VSCode?

Currently I've installed TSLint Globally:

`npm install -g tslint typescript`

and I've installed the TSLint extension... but I don't see any errors show up when I save my file.  Do I need to tell it to start working?

I'm new to VSCode and TSLint and Node, so the more specific, the better.

### Update

I am seeing this error now:

> vscode-tslint: Cannot read tslint configuration - 'Failed to load c:\Users\dlabar\Documents\GitHub\DefinitelyTyped\types\xrm\tslint.json:
>   Invalid "extends" configuration value - could not require
>   "dtslint/dt.json". Review the Node lookup algorithm
>   (https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) for the
>   approximate method TSLint uses to find the referenced configuration
>   file.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently node 7+ is required: https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint/issues/29

Upgraded and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar error message; but, in my case, it was due to not having installed a new dependency that `tslint.json` was referencing. Running `yarn install` (may be `npm install` for you) in the root of my project fixed the issue.